# Colors in bash after piping through less?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, less, ls

When I have dircolors defined life is full of... color.

When I pipe `ls` through `less` to scroll around I lose the colors.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Most likely your `ls` is aliased to `ls --color=auto`, which tells `ls` to only use colors when its output is a tty.  If you do `ls --color` (which is morally equivalent to `ls --color=always`), that will force it to turn on colors.

You could also change your alias to do that, but I wouldn't really call that a good idea.  Better to make a different alias with `--color`.

`less` needs `-R` too, which causes it to output the raw control characters.

Comment: Why would you not call it a good idea to alias ls to `ls --color` or `ls --color=always`, for that matter?

Comment: @j08lue if you pipe through a command that doesn't handle color, you get some junk characters that may mess up the command. For example, I did `ls --color=always | less` and got: `ESC[01;32mexecute_once.shESC[0m` (I know this is old and you probably don't care, but for future visitors, this may be useful)

Answer (score 65):

Try less with the -R option like this:

```
command | less -R
```

This works for me in a one-liner like this:

```
ls -la | grep --color=always bash | less -r
```

And like this too:

```
ls --color | less -R
```

But you have to tweak the primary output (the output of ls in this case) a bit with the --color parameter.

Comment: Thanks, this also works for ack-grep.  ack-grep my_string --color | less -R

Comment: --color is not recognized:  ls: illegal option -- -

Running bash on osx.

Comment: @Scott Biggs: in OSX there is no --color; try ls -G

Comment: @Lu-Chi, Even with `-G`, the colors are missing

Comment: In OS X you need to set the environment variable CLICOLOR_FORCE (to anything) when the output of ls isn't directed to a terminal. This works for me: CLICOLOR_FORCE= ls -G | less -R

Comment: The `-R` option is short for `--RAW-CONTROL-CHARS`.